# Using PyTest to create and run tests within Docker container

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, pytest

I'm trying to create a fixture that can take existing test files and execute them within a docker container. I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Non working code for reference.

###### test_foo.py

```
class TestClass:

    def test_example(self):
        a = 1
        b = 2
        assert a + b == 3
```

###### conftest.py

```
import docker as docker_py
import pytest


docker = docker_py.from_env()


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="class")
def generate_container(request):
    """ Create a container for all tests within class to run inside of """

    con = docker.containers.run(image="test_image", tty=True, detach=True)
    request.cls.container = con
    

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="function")
def run_tests_in_container(request):
    """
    Not sure how to get the contents of request.function 
    to execute inside of the docker container
    """

    output = request.cls.container.exec_run( ??? ) 

    exit_code = output[0]
    assert exit_code == 0
```

Ideally I'd like the test to only run inside the container. I think with my current approach the test will run inside the container and then run again on the host (unless I add in `pytest.skip` but that seems wrong)

Comment: Maybe have a look at [pytest-docker](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-docker/)? I haven't used it myself, but it looks like it could help.

Comment: Probably smth like `container.exec_run(['pytest', request.node.nodeid])`

Comment: @MrBeanBremen thanks for the suggestion. That package looks to be more focused on using docker services alongside pytest and not within it.

Comment: @hoefling thanks for pointing me towards `nodeid`! Documentation is not great for `requests`. I think I can make this work by sharing the test file with the container and using the `nodeid` to `exec_run` the tests one by one.

Comment: I have tried to use these python docker libraries a while ago and found it a bit cumbersome. I suggest you control everything with the docker tools and have a dev container, where pytest gets executed. I personally find it a bit awkward to do docker from within python. From my experience, what most people do is to use python/pytest within docker. Eventually, spending the time on learning how to to utilize the docker tools benefits you in a more general way.

Comment: I feel this is a cumbersome approach.  The easier way would be to *build* a container that has the libraries/dependencies for purest, the code to test (possible through an export) and you can run it inside the docker, as if you would on your local environment.